# Piping to Where-Object and Foreach.Object not working in module delayed loaded in $Profile

Tags: powershell, module, profile, runspace, scriptblock

**Preamble:** this is not about "fixing the code", as I already fixed it.
This is about "understanding what went wrong, so to avoid similar mistakes in future"

**Situation**:
Powershell 7.4.1.

I use [THIS](https://pastebin.com/QyCUA3GL) piece of code(which I got from some website I cannot recall) in my `$Profile` to delay-load modules and scripts. The live one has more code but not relevant: I've tested this is where the trouble is.

Specifically, I use it to load a Module I wrote for personal use.
(I know I don't actually need to load modules in my `$Profile` script as long as they are in my `$env:PSModulePath`; I'm sure there was a reason I did it but honestly cannot remember what.)

True contents of the original module do not matter as the Minimum Reproducible Example is:

**scirpt in `$profile`**

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8
# https://seeminglyscience.github.io/powershell/2017/09/30/invocation-operators-states-and-scopes
$GlobalState = [psmoduleinfo]::new($false)
$GlobalState.SessionState = $ExecutionContext.SessionState

$Job = Start-ThreadJob -Name TestJob -ArgumentList $GlobalState -ScriptBlock {
    $GlobalState = $args[0]
    . $GlobalState {

        # We always need to wait so that Get-Command itself is available
        do {
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
        } until (Get-Command Import-Module -ErrorAction Ignore)

        
        # other dot-sourced scripts...
        # . "$ProfileDirectory\CustomAlias.ps1"
        # . "$ProfileDirectory\CustomConstants.ps1"
        # . "$ProfileDirectory\CustomVariables.ps1"
        # . "$ProfileDirectory\CustomPrompt.ps1"

        # Import-Module -Name Sirtao
        Import-Module -Name Get-DirectoryItem

    }
}



$null = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Job -EventName StateChanged -SourceIdentifier Job.Monitor -Action {
    # JobState: NotStarted = 0, Running = 1, Completed = 2, etc.
    if ($Event.SourceEventArgs.JobStateInfo.State -eq 'Completed') {
        $Result = $Event.Sender | Receive-Job
        if ($Result) {
            $Result | Out-String | Write-Host
        }

        $Event.Sender | Remove-Job
        Unregister-Event Job.Monitor
        Get-Job Job.Monitor | Remove-Job
    }
    elseif ($Event.SourceEventArgs.JobStateInfo.State -gt 2) {
        $Event.Sender | Receive-Job | Out-String | Write-Host
    }
}
```

**Module loaded**

```
function Get-DirectoryItem {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'BaseSet')]
    [Alias('Get-Dir', 'GD')]
    param (
    )

    process {
        1..3 | Where-Object { $_ }
        1..3 | ForEach-Object { $_ }
        $a = @('a', 'b', 'c') 
        $a | ForEach-Object { $_ }
        $a | Where-Object { $_ }

    }
}
```

**What I did try:** simply running the command.

**What I was expecting:** the script returning the values of the arrays

**What I got:** the errors `ForEach-Object: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` and
`Where-Object: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Please note that `Get-Item`, `Get-ChildItem` and `Get-FileHash`, the only other examples of piping I used in my modules, do work as expected

**How i did fix it:** removing the import from the Job. The module was still imported automagically and everything worked as expected. But as i said, this is not about fixing, but *understanding*.

So... any ideas?

Comment: There is something we're not seeing in the code to reproduce the error, where is the Job you're mentioning ?

Comment: line 7 to 27 of the linked pastebin

Comment: right the minimal reproducible code should be here not in pastebin

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon edited original post with code of the profile script

Comment: It's an interesting question for sure, you can provide an easier way to reproduce the issue here: https://gist.github.com/santisq/a6ddbb057bc60a07bc4fc349e8afc26a // you can ask seeminglyscience himself in the pwsh discord, he sure has the answer as to why this happens :P

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - if you change the splat line in your gist to ```Value = 'function Test-Func { 0..10 | where-object { $_ }.Ast.GetScriptBlock() }'``` the code seems to magically start working. I don't claim to understand 100% why, but this page was the inspiration for guessing ```.Ast.GetScriptBlock()``` - https://mdgrs.hashnode.dev/scriptblock-and-sessionstate-in-powershell#heading-multi-runspace-scenario (I've linked to the key part, but the whole article is worth a read) - it seems to be something to do with the scope that the ```Test-Func``` function's body executes in...

Comment: @mclayton that's a very good point, totally forgot about it, this is one of the reasons why pwsh team implemented the [`NoRunspaceAffinity` decoration](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/18138). what `.Ast.GetScriptblock()` does is create a new scriptblock stripping the runspace affinity from it. see: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4003 for more info.

Comment: @mclayton funnily enough I think I understand why the issue happens, im guessing it happens because the runspace where the module was originated is dead as soon as the job ends so pwsh tries to marshal back to the origin runspace of that threadjob and implodes. see take2: https://gist.github.com/santisq/5d12b6d896cab233b5d3ef44e1ae1858#file-take2-ps1 also work while keeping the job's runspace alive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer attempts to explain why the issue happens but that does not mean implementing this for a *"faster profile loading"* is advisable.

---

First, an easier way to reproduce this issue:

```bash
$module = [psmoduleinfo]::new($false)
$module.SessionState = $ExecutionContext.SessionState

Start-ThreadJob {
    . $using:module {
        while (-not (Get-Command Import-Module -ErrorAction Ignore)) {
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
        }

        $newItemSplat = @{
            Value = 'function Test-Func { 0..10 | Where-Object { $_ } }'
            Path  = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString() + '.psm1'
        }

        $tmp = New-Item @newItemSplat
        Import-Module $tmp.FullName
        $tmp | Remove-Item
    }
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

Test-Func
```

As pointed out by [mclayton's helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton), adding [`.Ast.GetScriptblock()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.scriptblockast.getscriptblock?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-language-scriptblockast-getscriptblock) fixes the issue:

```bash
Value = 'function Test-Func { 0..10 | Where-Object { $_ }.Ast.GetScriptblock() }'
```

##### Why it fixes the issue?

Because `.GetScriptblock()` creates a new instance stripping out its Runspace affinity, this is something that has been discussed by Paul Higin (creator of the ThreadJob Module) in [GitHub issue #4003](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4003). See also [PR  #18138 - Make PowerShell class not affiliate with Runspace when declaring the `NoRunspaceAffinity` attribute](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/18138) for more information on this subject.

##### Why it fails?

This is based on guessing but when doing `. $using:module { ... Import-Module ... }` we are creating a nested module in that `PSModuleInfo` instance and when trying to invoke `Test-Func`, the `Where-Object` scriptblock is trying to marshal back to the originating Runspace which is no longer alive because the ThreadJob already ended, thus getting the null reference exception.

##### How to prove this is the case?

Because if we keep the originating Runspace alive the issue is gone :)

```bash
$module = [psmoduleinfo]::new($false)
$module.SessionState = $ExecutionContext.SessionState
$rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$rs.Open()

$ps = [powershell]::Create($rs).AddScript({
    . $args[0] {
        while (-not (Get-Command Import-Module -ErrorAction Ignore)) {
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
        }

        $newItemSplat = @{
            Value = 'function Test-Func { 0..10 | Where-Object { $_ } }'
            Path  = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString() + '.psm1'
        }

        $tmp = New-Item @newItemSplat
        Import-Module $tmp.FullName
        $tmp | Remove-Item
    }
}).AddArgument($module)

$task = $ps.BeginInvoke()
while (-not $task.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(200)) { }

Test-Func
```

---

Additional info for anyone looking to dig deeper into the root cause, I believe [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) has again provided the key source blocks causing this exception to be thrown:

- [ExecutionContext.cs#L1144-L1155](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/4f02a89906a92f684ff4511ae74958f602edf800/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/ExecutionContext.cs#L1144-L1155) sets `Events = null;` when the runspace is disposed.
- Then, in [`ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(...)`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/4f02a89906a92f684ff4511ae74958f602edf800/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/lang/scriptblock.cs#L1006-L1040), it tries to reference the `.Events` property: [`context.Events.SubscribeEvent(...)`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/4f02a89906a92f684ff4511ae74958f602edf800/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/lang/scriptblock.cs#L1008) which is already `null` causing the NRE.

Comment: I've spent probably *too* long digging into this - it looks like when the ```Start-ThreadJob``` runspace closes it triggers this https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/4f02a89906a92f684ff4511ae74958f602edf800/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/ExecutionContext.cs#L1151, which is then the cause of the "Object reference not set" error when the ```Where-Object -Filter``` scriptblock tries to execute: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/4f02a89906a92f684ff4511ae74958f602edf800/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/lang/scriptblock.cs#L1008

Comment: And the reason it follows that ```shouldGenerateEvent``` path is because further up the second link the ```if (SessionStateInternal != null && SessionStateInternal.ExecutionContext != context)``` is true because the Filter scriptblock is being invoked from a different ExecutionContext to the one it's bound to, so it uses Events to signal execution on the (now closed) context rather than running it locally with ```InvokeWithPipeImpl```. Short story - don't try to import modules in a temporary runspace (e.g. inside ```Start-ThreadJob```) and expect them to work after the runspace is closed :-)

Comment: @mclayton thanks for the insights, the issue is unrelated to `Start-ThreadJob` imo, as you can see with pure runspace code (in my answer), if you `$rs.Dispose()` before invoking `Test-Func` you will get the same null reference exception. `InvokeWithPipe` requires a runspace that is alive to run :P

Comment: Yeah - they're basically the same underlying cause that the target runspace is closed - it'd be nice if the error message was something like "Can't execute scriptblocks on a closed runspace" rather than "Object reference not set" but \o/...

Comment: @mclayton so you definitely hit the nail there, looking at the source in detail, context sets `Events` to `null` then the scriptblock re-throws the null reference: `scriptBlockInvocationEventArgs.Exception?.Throw();`

Comment: @mclayton I agree reg. the exception being more clear but if you think about it, as a dev on the pwsh team would you expect someone to do something like this? trying to create a nested module in a different runspace that is added to the default runspace's execution context? It goes beyond what is supported (why I put that disclaimer on top of the answer) would never recommend even trying something like this but it is interesting to debug for sure :D

Comment: I'm kinda happy this is actually something complicated(and WAAAAY above my current skill. Something to go back later, that's sure). Thanks everybody for your efforts. That said: do you believe this can be classified as a "bug" or a "feature request: better error message in ultra-niche case"?

Comment: @sirtao - one man’s bug is another’s feature request :-). I’d lean to the latter though, tbh. The code fails because the runspace is closed - it’s just failing due to an internal “null reference” exception rather than a deliberate “throw”. You could raise an “improvement” issue on the PowerShell GitHub repo at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell if you want to flag it up…

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - I think it’s more that the code fails at [```context.Events.SubscribeEvent( … )```](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/4f02a89906a92f684ff4511ae74958f602edf800/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/lang/scriptblock.cs#L1008) because ```context.Events``` is ```null```…

Comment: Thanks @mclayton you're right, fails at first reference of that property. Updated the answer // sirtao, this is not a bug